# dbms_scheduler job chain exceptions

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, scheduler, dbms-scheduler

I'd like to find the best way to handle exceptions (failure of any steps) from an Oracle scheduler job chain (11gR2).

Say I have a chain that contains 20 steps.  If at any point the chain exits with FAILURE, I'd like to do a set of actions.  These actions are specific to that chain, not the individual steps (each step's procedure may be used outside of scheduler or in other chains).

Thanks to 11gR2, I can now setup an email notification on FAILURE of chain, but this is only 1 of several actions I need to do, so its only a partial solution for me.

The only thing I can think of is have another polling job check the status of my chain every x minutes and launch the failure actions when it sees the latest job of the chain exited with FAILURE status.  But this is a hack at best imo.

What is the best way to handle exceptions for a given job chain?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most flexible way to handle jobs exceptions in general is to use a job exception monitoring procedure and define the jobs to generate events upon job status changes. The job exception monitoring procedure should watch the `scheduler event queue` in a loop and react upon events in a way you define.

Doing so takes away the burden to have to create failure steps for about each and every job step in a chain. This is a very powerful mechanism.

by lack of time: [in the book is a complete scenario](http://www.packtpub.com/mastering-oracle-scheduler-in-oracle-11g-databases/book) of event based scheduling. Will dig one up later.

Comment: thanks.  So I'd use Oracle AQ and raise a failure event from my chain, then setup a separate event based job using that queue?  Not much experience with AQ, can u give a simple example?  thanks again

Comment: Hi, see comments; have to run now, later!

Comment: Lucky for me, the one free chapter they give for this book is on events!  I won't copy/paste example from the book tho, and will probably still buy the ebook, looks good.  Thanks @ik_zelf , if you have a simple example for everyone, it would still be much appreciated.

Comment: some guys have all the luck ;-) Glad that you could use it and I saw the article I thought about is missing from my blog. I will soon add it there.